# Unable to import education from LinkedIn to Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

When importing from [my LinkedIn profile](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=49442308), both jobs and education show up on the import page. However, after pressing "import this", jobs were imported correctly, but the education was not (even though there were no error messages and "Imported!" was shown).

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now.  We were silently discarding entries without the first field (Title for jobs, Degree for education).  Now we keep them around, though you should probably go back in and add a degree if it makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be fixed. My degree is written in LinkedIn as "BSc (Hons), Artificial Intelligence", but was imported as just "BSc (Hons)"

Comment: @Will This sounds like a different issue.  The original post here was somebody whose entry didn't get imported at all.  You should open up a separate bug report for your issue.